# Reverse geocoding - getting postal code with geopy.Nominatim

Tags: python, reverse-geocoding, geopy, postal-code, nominatim

I am trying already for a few hours and I don't know what I should do. I have a dataframe with latitude and longitude data:

```
    year  month        lat        lon       SMI
0   2010      1  47.266481  10.149783  0.830187
1   2010      2  47.266481  10.149783  0.754513
2   2010      3  47.266481  10.149783  0.663457
3   2010      4  47.266481  10.149783  0.407255
4   2010      5  47.266481  10.149783  0.972982
5   2010      6  47.266481  10.149783  0.147511
6   2010      7  47.266481  10.149783  0.085912
7   2010      8  47.266481  10.149783  0.936917
8   2010      9  47.266481  10.149783  0.673884
9   2010     10  47.266481  10.149783  0.242676
10  2010     11  47.266481  10.149783  0.797547
11  2010     12  47.266481  10.149783  0.923627
12  2011      1  47.266481  10.149783  0.895137
13  2011      2  47.266481  10.149783  0.471502
14  2011      3  47.266481  10.149783  0.340169
```

Per month I have 23,199 different geographical points and I have to match them with their respective postal code (Germany).

Based on this discussion(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352961/convert-lat-lon-to-zip-postal-code-using-python), I came up with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy

geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "myMAil"

def get_zipcode(subsmi, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field):
    location = geolocator.reverse((subsmi[lat_field], subsmi[lon_field]))
    return location.raw['address']['postcode']


geolocator = geopy.Nominatim()

zipcodes = subsmi.apply(get_zipcode, axis=1, geolocator=geolocator, lat_field='lat', lon_field='lon')
```

The code works as long the dataframe is kept at 10 rows. As soon as I want to apply that code to a dataframe that contains more than 10 rows, KeyError: 'postcode' appears.
I know that Nominatim limits the number of points that one can reverse. Does anyone have an idea how I can alter the code so I can reverse all of my points ultimately.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that it was the data itself, some pair s of lat and log were wrong, that's why it shows keyError. To solve this, I tried this one and worked. please try:

```
def get_zipcode(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field, attempt=1, max_attempts=100):
    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse((df[lat_field], df[lon_field]), timeout=None)
        return location.raw['address']['postcode']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    except GeocoderTimedOut:
        if attempt <= max_attempts:
            return get_zipcode (df, attempt=attempt+1)
        raise
```

Answer (score -1):

If the limit is Nominatim as you think it is and option could be separating your data into chunks of 10 and check them 10 by 10 until you find the closest solution.

I've also found that there's a rate_limiter function to allow bulk operations, that may also be a solution for you, I'll link the documentation.

Rate limiter link: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=rate%20limiter#module-geopy.extra.rate_limiter

Comment: I tried to implement a rate limiter but I keep getting the same error but I am going to try to separate the data in chunks. Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be in a dictionary somewhere, maybe you could also try and handle the error and see if it at least gives you most of the zipcodes, maybe there's just a wrong type on your dataset.